# Raspberry PI Zero DS3231 RTC

Tags: raspberry-pi, real-time-clock, hwclock

I have an Raspberry PI Zero and want to add a HWClock DS3231 (https://www.amazon.de/DS3231-RTC-Modul-f%C3%BCr-Raspberry/dp/B01B4IV30C/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_2?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1486456449&sr=8-2-fkmr0&keywords=raspberry+pi+zero+rtc) on it.

On my Raspberry PI 3 B it works fine. But when i try to use it on my Zero it won't work.

Im not sure if i put the RTC on the right GPIO Pins havn't found any How-To for it. Is anyone out there who has a Raspberry PI Zero working with a DS3231 RTC Modul?

Thanks for your Help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGZ3o.jpg)